# Private class data design pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm reading about **private class data design pattern** [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/private_class_data) and I'm trying to understand what it can really accomplish.

From what I understood private class data design pattern is a structural pattern aiming to reproduce "readonly" attributes even for the class itself: while "private" attributes are visible and editable only to the class itself, attributes in the "private class data" can't be changed at all (even by accident). The only solution is to provide a setter in the private class data, although (at least in my opinion) if the private class data has all the setters of the attributes, then we might have defeated the pattern very purpose.

Assuming my understanding is correct, this lead to a question: *Even if the main class can't change any private class data attributes, it can set the reference of the private class data itself, populating it with the variables it wants to change*.

In other words, an uncaring developer might do something like this:

```
public class MainData {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    public MainData(int foo, int bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    } 
    public int getFoo() {return foo;}
    public int getBar() {return bar;}
}
public class Main {
    private MainData mainData;
    public Main(int foo, int bar) {
        this.mainData = new MainData(foo, bar);
    }
    public doSomeWork() {
        //correct behaviour
        this.mainData.getFoo() + this.mainData.getBar();
        //now I want to trick the pattern
        this.mainData = new MainData(this.mainData.getFoo(), this.mainData.getBar()+4);
        //I've changed bar :(
    }
}
```

Since the "readonly" attribute is not compile-enforced (unlike C# via `readonly` reserved word), in Java a lazy developer might do something like this. If it's true, then why should we use this design pattern at all? Unlike other patterns (like singleton) this pattern doesn't enforce anything, so why should we using it at all?

- It would be great if you can provide example where you've used this pattern and it concretely helped you solving some software issue;
- Let's stay on Java: I know in C# everything is much easier, but there the pattern is just plain silly because of `readonly` reserved word;

Thanks for any kind reply!

Comment: In your example, sure, it's easy to write code IN the class that has the private fields, but the point is that no code OUTSIDE of the class can ever change it.

Comment: I think Oracle will not be happy with your avatar http://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/209/is-it-ok-to-use-a-java-logo-in-my-business-card

Comment: @HRgiger I think I'll need to change that avatar then

Comment: @Zircon: why don't just use the private modifier? Can't you achieve the same result with that? What's the difference?

Comment: Wont making it `private final MainData mainData` solve this replacement issue?

Comment: @Micheal Anderson. Yeah, that will solve the trick to avoid private data class. Ok, now since the pattern can enforce its semantic one part of the question is clear. I still need to find concrete example on why use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The author that wrote the `Private Class Data` says that the intent of that so called pattern is:

> **Intent**
>
> - Control write access to class attributes
> - Separate data from methods that use it
> - Encapsulate class data initialization
> - Providing new type of final - final after constructor

Let's take a look at the intents one by one

> Control write access to class attributes

My Opinion is that controling write access to class attributes is simply done by methods and modifiers. OOP calls this [`Encapsulation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Encapsulation)

> Separate data from methods that use it

That doesn't make much sense to me, because object oriented programming means to bring data and methods together. That what an object is about. Separating data from methods that use it seems to be an anemic approach.

> Encapsulate class data initialization

That is what I do in a constructor. I don't see the benefit of moving this code to another class.

> Providing new type of final - final after constructor

This intent aims to make the reference to the data class final, but don't make the attributes in the data class final. I guess that is why it is called a "new type of final". Since the data class only holds data and the methods are separated from them, the data can not be modified if there is no setter on the data class. In this case the data is immutable. Thus I don't see the benefit of a data class to just making the class's field final.

**My conclusion**

I think that this so called pattern adds complexity without much benefit. Therefore I would not use it. And I call it a "so called pattern", because

> [In software engineering, a software design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)

I don't see the commonly occuring problem.

Comment: I can see the roots of your argument (I posted this question because I had them too). Probably this pattern is useless in Java too (as it is in C#). Maybe in some other language (maybe Python?) it might make sense. Netherless, I'm marking you answer as the correct one

Comment: Also having a class with only data members and no methods will give rise to "Broken Modularization" design smell. See this link:http://www.tusharma.in/smells/BM.html

Answer (score 0):

Members of the private (or inner) class are not "Read only" at all.
There is no problem changing their values, via setter method or even directly.

Having "Read only" members is not a reason to use private classes. One reason to do so is that the class should only be accessed in the scope of the containing (or outer) class.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please be more specific? According to [source making](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/private_class_data)  (Discussion or problem section) the purpose of the private data class seems to restrict changes in the attrbutes, rather than accessibility (the UML diagram seems to support this hypothesis of mine). If I wanted to reduce accessbility, shouldn't I just use an inner class? In that way only the main class could access the members.

Comment: The page you were referring to says: "... reduce exposure of attributes by limiting their visibility". It does not mean completely "read only", just less accessible. Once a (private) member is inside an inner class, it is visible by a smaller scope. But still, visible and editable from inside the inner class.

Comment: ok, I can agree with you about the characteristics of inner classes. But I still can't grasp how your answer relates with my question. Even supposing `MainData` is a innerclass, an uncaring developer might perform the same trick I exploited in the main question (thereby rendering the use of the inner class meaningless)(even better, it could directly set the private members). So why should we use this particular pattern? Probably I didn't understand your point.